# Create encapsulated array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object like this:

```
"1": "test1"
"1.1": "test2"
"1.1.1": "test3"
"1.2": "test4"
"2": "test5"
```

and I would like to create an array like this:

```
"data": [
  {"data": "test1",
  "children": [
    {"data": "test2",
    "children": [{"data": "test3"}]},
    {"data": "test4"}]},
  {"data": "test5"}
]
```

I began to loop the list and split the keys with a dot.
I thought maybe I could first build an returnArray[splitedkey[0]][splitedkey[1]] but I dont know how many levels my list has.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide the code you wrote so far - you will have to use a recursion for a reliable way to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var a = {"1": "test1", "1.1": "test2", "1.1.1": "test3", "1.2": "test4", "2": "test5"};
var b = {data: []};
Object.keys(a).forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
    if (item.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
        console.log(item, a[item]);
        var sp = item.split(".");
        var parent = b.data[sp[0] - 1];
        for (var i = 1; i < sp.length - 1; i++) {
            parent = parent.children[sp[i] - 1];
        }
        parent.children.push({data: a[item], children: []});
    } else {
        b.data.push({data: a[item], children: []});
    }
});
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-obvious issues that you'll encounter with this:

- Iterating through keys in objects may not conform to the order you wrote them. There's a chance an algorithm will encounter `1.1.1` before encountering `1`, so an implementation will need to make blank parents `{ data: null, children [] }`
- It's clearly a recursive data structure, must be careful that the recursive algorithm terminates properly with duff data

Here's one solution. `setVal` will recursively crawl to the correct depth specified by `accessPath`, an array of accessors (e.g. `[1, 1, 1]`). `nestObj` reads through `obj`, extracts keys, maps them to indicies, and appends them into your return value.

```js
var obj = {
  "1": "test1",
  "1.1": "test2",
  "1.1.1": "test3",
  "1.2": "test4",
  "2": "test5"
}

function setVal (array, accessPath, val) {
  if (accessPath.length === 1) {
    if (array[accessPath] === undefined)
      array[accessPath] = { data: val, children: [] };
    else
      array[accessPath].data = val;
  } else {
    // Deals with out-of-order iteration
    if (array[accessPath[0]] === undefined)
      array[accessPath[0]] = { data: null, children: [] };

    setVal(array[accessPath[0]].children, accessPath.slice(1), val);        
  }
}

function nestObj (obj) {
  var ret = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    var val = obj[key];
    var accessPath = key.split(".").map(function (entry) {
                                      return parseInt(entry, 10);
                                    });
    setVal(ret, accessPath, val);
  });
  return ret;
}

// The format you specified
var answer = { data: nestObj(obj) };

console.log(obj)
console.log(answer)
```

You don't necessarily *need* to use `parseInt` on the access keys. This algorithim would (mostly) work with any arbitrary string key *via* an associative array.